# Baby Rudin theorem 6.16 - Why does $ \int_a^b f d \alpha_2 \ $ exist?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Theorem 6.16 in Principles of Mathematical Analysis by Walter Rudin, 3rd edition:

> **6.16 Theorem** Suppose $c_n \geq 0$ for $n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots$, $\sum c_n$ converges, $\left\{ s_n \right\}$ is a sequence of distinct points in $(a, b)$, and
> $$\tag{22} \alpha(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n I \left(x-s_n \right). $$
> Let $f$ be continuous on $[a, b]$. Then
> $$\tag{23}  \int_a^b f d \alpha = \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n f \left( s_n \right). $$
> **Proof** The comparison test shows that the series (22) converges for every $x$. Its sum $\alpha(x)$ is evidently monotonic, and $\alpha(a) = 0$, $\alpha(b) = \sum c_n$.
> Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be given, and choose $N$ so that
> $$ \sum_{N+1}^\infty c_n < \varepsilon. $$
> Put
> $$ \alpha_1(x) = \sum_{n=1}^N c_n I \left( x-s_n \right), \qquad \alpha_2(x) = \sum_{N+1}^\infty c_n I \left( x - s_n \right). $$
> By Theorems 6.12 and 6.15,
> $$\tag{24} \int_a^b f d \alpha_1 = \sum_{n=1}^N c_n f \left( s_n \right). $$
> Since $\alpha_2(b) - \alpha_2(a) < \varepsilon$,
> $$ \tag{25} \left\lvert \int_a^b f d \alpha_2 \right\rvert \leq M \varepsilon, $$
> where $M = \sup \lvert f(x) \rvert$. Since $\alpha = \alpha_1 + \alpha_2$, it follows from (24) and (25) that
> $$\tag{26} \left\lvert \int_a^b f d\alpha - \sum_{n=1}^N c_n f \left( s_n \right) \right\rvert \leq M \varepsilon.$$
> If we let $N \to \infty$, we obtain (23).

I understand this to be the process by which (24) is obtained:

$$
\begin{align}
\int_a^b f d\alpha_1 &= \int_a^b f(x) d\left( \sum_{n=1}^N c_n I \left( x-s_n \right) \right) \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^N \int_a^b f(x) d \left( c_n I \left( x- s_n \right) \right) \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^N c_n \int_a^b f(x) d \left( I \left( x-s_n \right) \right) \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^N c_n f \left( s_n \right).
\end{align}
$$

Is this still valid if we replace $\alpha_1$ with $\alpha_2$ and $\sum_{n=1}^N$ with $\sum_{n=N + 1}^\infty$? If not, how does one derive the existence of $ \int_a^b f d \alpha_2 \ $ in (25)?

Comment: Have a look at Theorem 6.8. All of the relevant integrals exist because $f$ is continuous and $\alpha$ [$\alpha_i$] is bounded nondecreasing.

Comment: Ahhh thank you! I suppose this also directly follows from Theorem 6.10 because ***f*** has no points of discontinuity.

Comment: Ah, that means you can generalize this Theorem 6.16 a little.

Comment: Yeah. 6.16 still holds even if $f$ is discontinuous at finitely many points, all of which are not in the closure of { $s_n$ }'s range.